# Geometric intuition behind an n-dimensional rotation matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, linear-transformations, rotations

How do I derive an n-dimensional rotation matrix from a geometric perspective? I have read on wikipedia that it preserves distance so that $Q^TQ = I$ but the explanation to be honest isn't very clear. I've had a thorough look on Google and can't find a decent explanation that starts from the geometry first. Also, on Wikipedia (see here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_matrix) it says that $det(Q) = 1$ but it isn't clear at all why! Thanks.

Comment: You may find interesting https://youtu.be/0rEz9-6trHw

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you mean by "deriving something from a geometric perspective", but you might find this question relevant: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2872052/are-orthonormal-matrices-rotations/2872077#2872077.

Comment: Beware: there is not any commonly accepted definition of "rotation matrix" when the size of the matrix is larger than 3 by 3.

Comment: You can think about rotation matrices as members of the group of symmetries of a sphere centred at the origin. These are called in general "orthogonal matrices". Not all symmetries of the sphere are called 'rotations' - some are called 'reflections' - see also the comment above me - from user1551.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Suppose $Q$ is an $n\times n$ matrix that preserves distance.  Heuristically, that would mean that
$$
    \Vert Qx-Qy \Vert = \Vert x - y \Vert
$$
for all $n$-vectors $x$ and $y$.  Now if you use the polarization identity
$$
    \left<x,y\right> = \frac{1}{4}\left(\Vert x+y \Vert^2 - \Vert x-y\Vert^2\right)
$$
you can show that preserving distances is equivalent to preserving the inner product.  So $Q$ preserves distances if and only if
$$
    \left<Qx,Qy\right> = \left<x,y\right>
$$
for all $x$ and $y$.  Using the defining property of the transpose, we can move it over:
$$
    \left<Qx,Qy\right> = \left<x,y\right> \implies \left<x,Q^TQy\right> = \left<x,y\right>
$$
for all $x$ and $y$.  From this follows that $Q^TQ = I$.  A nice consequence is that if treat the columns of $Q$ as vectors, they form an *othonormal* set: each has unit length, and each pair are orthogonal (perpendicular).

Now using determinant properties, you have that $\det Q^2 = \det I = 1$.  So $\det Q = \pm 1$.

But this all comes from the distance-preserving property of $Q$.  If you consider $\mathbb{R}^n$ as an *oriented* vector space, you can determine if distance-preserving matrices preserve or reverse the orientation.  The condition of preserving the orientation is equivalent to the determinant of $Q$ being $1$.

Comment: This is a decent answer. But unfortunately I’m confused by the last paragraph. I don’t understand what you mean by an oriented vector space - so you lost me! I looked on google and saw a rough proof that a rotation matrix must have determinant 1 since determinant is a continuous function and thus rotation and identity matrices must have the same determinant (1). However, I’d still like to understand what you mean - so I will google ‘preserving orientation’ so I can understand your last paragraph. Thanks

Comment: Fair point.  I had to be a bit vague in that last paragraph because, like user1551 says, there isn't really a notion of rotation matrix for dimensions higher than 3 that's independent of the determinant property. I'll try to put in something for $n=2$ that might help.

Comment: To be honest, I’d prefer if any answer only relates to n by n matrices so that it’s generally applicable. I can mark yours as answer as it’s close enough